# How to differentiate $y=x^{y^{\sin x}}$

Tags: derivatives

I know I'll have to use implicit differentiation, but I always get stuck when there is an exponent with trig, log, and/or natural log.

Comment: As currently written, the expression is difficult to decipher.

Comment: @Kaaagome pls check edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1**$$y=x^{y^{\sin x}}$$
$$\ln y=y^{\sin x}\ln x$$
$$\frac1y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^{\sin x}}{x}+\ln x\left[\frac{d}{dx}y^{\sin x}\right]$$

Now find derivative of $y^{\sin x}$ and then rearrngement

---

**Approach 2**
$$y=x^{y^{\sin x}}$$

$$\ln y=y^{\sin x}\ln x$$
$$\ln(\ln y)=\ln(y^{\sin x})+\ln(\ln x)$$

$$\ln(\ln y)={\sin x}\ln(y)+\ln(\ln x)$$

I hope You can take it from here!

---

> **Note:** Question was edited after posting answer given below

$$$$

> $$((x^{y})^{sinx})^{6}=x^{6y\sin x}$$

$$y=x^{6y\sin x}$$
$$\ln y=6y\sin x\ln x$$

$$\frac1y\frac{dy}{dx}=6\sin x\ln x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{6y\sin x}{x}+6y\cos x\ln x$$
$$\left(\frac1y-6\sin x\ln x\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6y\sin x}{x}+6y\cos x\ln x$$
$$\left(\frac{1-6y\sin x\ln x}{y}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6y\sin x}{x}+6y\cos x\ln x$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(6y\sin x+6xy\cos x\ln x)}{x(1-6y\sin x\ln x)}$$

Now it's all about simplification, *Just like last time*

Comment: At what point is this no longer a hint? haha

Comment: Of course! I was just laughing to myself!

Comment: thank you for the answer, but someone edited the title wrong. it's y=x^(y^sinx)

Comment: Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y(y\sin x+xy\cos x\ln x)}{x(1-y\sin x\ln x)}$

Comment: oh my gosh thank you so much! approach 2 makes alot of sense! i tried something like that, but i forgot that property where u can add the two ln's together! thank you!